# Inventory ID that combines fields

Tags: acumatica, inventory

Anyone know if it's possible to combine a field like Item Class (we use a 3 letter code for each one) with a sequential number to get a unique Inventory ID?

e.g. we need all hardware to be HWR-00988 but all Shipping Supplies to be SUP-00989 and so on.

My workaround right now is to create an Attribute called ITEMCLASS and basically mirror the item class codes (HWR, SUP, etc) then add attributes to each Item Class and use the Inventory ID Segment Settings to make it look like it's pulling the actual Item Class.

Seems like this should exist though? I know the data exists in INITEMMENU already.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean having a unique InventoryCD key that switches between constants HWR-XXXXX and SUP-XXXXX based on custom business rules (like appending Item Class); I don't think that's possible out-of-box without programming.

Usually this is accomplished with a custom attribute. Here's an example for [CuryID] attribute which computes key value based on arbitrary logic.

Usage, decorate key fields with custom attribute [CuryID]:

```
[PXDBString(5, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.baseCuryID))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Currency", ErrorHandling = PXErrorHandling.Never)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Currency.curyID))]
[CuryID]
public virtual String CuryID { get; set; }
```

For your scenario you would replace InventoryRaw with your custom attribute:

```
[PXDefault]
[InventoryRaw(IsKey = true, DisplayName = "Inventory ID")]
public virtual String InventoryCD { get; set; }
```

Custom attribute [CuryID], if key is autogenerated consider adding FieldDefaulting event:

```
public sealed class CuryIDAttribute : PXEventSubscriberAttribute, IPXFieldUpdatedSubscriber, IPXRowSelectedSubscriber, IPXRowUpdatingSubscriber, IPXRowUpdatedSubscriber, IPXFieldVerifyingSubscriber
{
    public void FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrencyInfo info = e.Row as CurrencyInfo;
        if (info != null)
        {
            //reset effective date to document date first
            info.SetDefaultEffDate(sender);
            try
            {
                info.defaultCuryRate(sender);
            }
            catch (PXSetPropertyException ex)
            {
                sender.RaiseExceptionHandling(_FieldName, e.Row, sender.GetValue(e.Row, _FieldOrdinal), ex);
            }
            info.CuryPrecision = null;
        }
    }
    public void RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrencyInfo info = e.Row as CurrencyInfo;
        if (info != null)
        {
            bool disabled = info.IsReadOnly == true || (info.CuryID == info.BaseCuryID);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CurrencyInfo.curyMultDiv>(sender, info, !disabled);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CurrencyInfo.sampleCuryRate>(sender, info, !disabled);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CurrencyInfo.sampleRecipRate>(sender, info, !disabled);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CurrencyInfo.curyRateTypeID>(sender, info, !disabled);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CurrencyInfo.curyEffDate>(sender, info, !disabled);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CurrencyInfo.baseCuryID>(sender, info, false);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CurrencyInfo.displayCuryID>(sender, info, false);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CurrencyInfo.curyID>(sender, info, true);
        }
    }
    private bool? currencyInfoDirty = null;
    public void RowUpdating(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrencyInfo info = e.Row as CurrencyInfo;
        if (info != null && info._IsReadOnly == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            currencyInfoDirty = sender.IsDirty;
        }
    }
    public void RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrencyInfo info = e.Row as CurrencyInfo;
        if (info != null)
        {
            CurrencyInfo old = e.OldRow as CurrencyInfo;
            if (old != null && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(info.CuryID) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(info.BaseCuryID)))
            {
                info.BaseCuryID = old.BaseCuryID;
                info.CuryID = old.CuryID;
            }
            if (currencyInfoDirty == false
                && info.CuryID == old.CuryID
                && info.CuryRateTypeID == old.CuryRateTypeID
                && info.CuryEffDate == old.CuryEffDate
                && info.CuryMultDiv == old.CuryMultDiv
                && info.CuryRate == old.CuryRate)
            {
                sender.IsDirty = false;
                currencyInfoDirty = null;
            }
        }
    }
    public void FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrencyInfo info = e.Row as CurrencyInfo;
        if (info != null)
        {
            CMSetup CMSetup = info.getCMSetup(sender);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Was definitely hoping for something out of the box but will pass this idea onto the consultants who are "helping" us implement. I think it would be equally acceptable if the Item Class ID just shows up on all the reports for now. 

Appreciate your feedback :)

Comment: It seems like programming will be required. Note that while a custom attribute provides a transparent and native solution there are alternative methods and workarounds which are easier to implement than my answer.